# Template Does not exist

Tags: django

I am new to Django. I use pydev eclipse as an IDE. First I created a project then an application welcome on that project. I made a folder named Templates within the project and make a file "home.html" and home.html contains

```
<div>
This is my first site
</div>
```

I modify the settings.py file as

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ("Templates")

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ..........#all default items
    'welcome', #the added one
)
```

views.py includes

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('home.html')
```

urls.py contains

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from welcome.views import home
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'MajorProject.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^home/$', home),

)
```

then I run it as django project and open my browser and see on localhost:8000/home
it shows error

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /home/
home.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/home/
Django Version: 1.6
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
home.html
Exception Location: C:\Python27\django\template\loader.py in find_template, line 131
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.2
Python Path:    
['D:\\Bishnu\\BE\\4th year\\8th semester\\Major Project II\\Working\\Workspace\\MajorProject',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg',
 'D:\\Bishnu\\BE\\4th year\\8th semester\\Major Project II\\Working\\Workspace\\MajorProject',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode',
 'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip']
Server time:    Sun, 2 Jun 2013 14:25:52 +0545
```

Comment: Try to use absolute path, not a relative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to set Templates Directory on `setting.py`.
as

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
                    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates'),
)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Django 1.8+

You'll get this warning:

```
(1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put the values of the following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict: TEMPLATE_DIRS, TEMPLATE_DEBUG.
```

Add your template directory to the Base TEMPLATES setting under the DIRS dictionary

Like so:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            root("templates"), #### Here ####
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 2):

in Django 1.9

```
in settings.py
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [BASE_DIR+r'\templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            ...
        ],
    },
},
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Directory with templates should be named `templates`, not `Templates` (even though on windows it may be the same). Also make sure, you have application in `PYTHONPATH` or the correct directory structure of your project and application like:

```
project/
    project/
        settings.py
        ...
    welcome/
        templates/
            home.html
        views.py
        ...
  manage.py
```

Then you don't need to change `TEMPLATE_DIRS` because [`app_directories.Loader`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader) (enabled by default) will find the templates in your application.

Also of if you still want to change `TEMPLATE_DIRS`, use absolute paths, but preferred way is the [`app_directories.Loader`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader).

Answer (score 0):

## check below steps to fix

## step 1:

Inside templates, 'DIRS' : [ ], metion this:

'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],

## step 2:

Go in your views.py file and look for template_name (check its spelling and also check did you mentioned the right html file here or not)

## step 3:

Check in your urls.py file wether you mentioned the right template name or not in the path

format: urlpatterns = [ path(" ", class name or function name, name = template name)

Answer (score 0):

BASE_DIR = Path(**file**).resolve().parent.parent

This is default directory code by Django
And looks like this
C:\user\pc_name\django_project

But if you delete last .parent it will looks like this
C:\user\pc_name\django_project\django_project

So new BASE_DIR code which is this
BASE_DIR = Path(**file**).resolve().parent

Add this variable to TEMPLATE_DIR
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'template")

And last code define this
C:\user\pc_name\django_project\django_project\template

In the end safely uptade DIRS
'DIRS': 'TEMPLATE_DIR'

Hope you did

Comment: This answer is not formatted correctly and may become hard to read. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for formatting help.