# TemplateDoesNotExist at / learning_logs/index.html

Tags: python, django

Im following a tutorial about Django and I got this error and I dont know why its happening since Im following a book tutorial, I didnt have any error until now and I checked every piece of code, maybe its because Im using a new versio of Django?

This is settings

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'REDACTED'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # My apps
    'learning_logs',

    # Default django apps.
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'learning_log.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'learning_log.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

This is views

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    """The home page for Learning Log."""
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')
```

This is urls

```
"""Defines URL patterns for learning_logs."""

from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'learning_logs'
urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index')
```

I just followed every step in the book and the folders paths for the projects so why I have this problem?

Comment: Can you share your folder structure. I think you might not have structure,  learning_logs -> templates -> learning_logs -> index.html

Comment: C:\Users\carlo\Downloads\learning_log\learning_logs\templates\learning_logs this the path of the file index.html

Comment: you should change your SECRET_KEY now that it's been posted publicly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Template Does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870957/template-does-not-exist)

Comment: Im not sure what do I have to change, it says add somethin to a file but where exactly? Also in the tutorial theres nothing about that

Comment: did you include the app url to your project url?

Comment: What does that means?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was the html files were not actually html instead they were .txt

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue but my error was that I forgot to make another learning_logs folder inside the templates folder.
Another error was that I did not create an html file but a text file for 'index.html'.
Download a sample html file from online (https://filesamples.com/formats/html) and rename it to just "index" and edit it to include the content shown in the book.

Answer (score 0):

step 1:
**for urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "learning_logs"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
]
```

step 2:
**for views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render


# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

step 3:
Make a templates folder inside learning_logs app then, make a index.html folder inside templates folder......that's all.

[image: this the templates path.]

Note: try this step.. this problem will be solve.